# How to split selected columns from the choices menu in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In R shiny, I used the SelectInput function, which allows me to select column names like as "ID" and "Type," as well as a browse button to upload a csv file and a "SplitColumn" button to unmerge combined columns.

What I want to do is, I should select the merged column from the choices menu, in this example 'Type,' and run the source code "SplitColumn.R" to unmerge the column and observe the results after uploading the csv file.

**Issue**

I have not yet received any errors, but the unmerge works without the need to use the "SplitColumn" button. When I select the option from the options themselves, the unmerge works.

Could someone please assist me with whatever I'm missing in the ui/server code?

**csv data**

```
ID  Type   Range
21  A1 B1   100
22  C1 D1   200
23  E1 F1   300
```

**SplitColumn.R**

```
splitColumn <- function(data, column_name) {
  newColNames <- c("Unmerged_type1", "Unmerged_type2")
  newCols <- colsplit(data[[column_name]], " ", newColNames)
  after_merge <- cbind(data, newCols)
  after_merge[[column_name]] <- NULL
  after_merge
}
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

source('splitColumn_stack.R')

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      actionButton("Splitcolumn", "SplitColumn"),
      selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', choices=c('ID, Type'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observe({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    rv$data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(rv$data)
    rv$data
  })
  # column_name <- dlg_input("Enter a number", Sys.info()["user"])$res
  
  observeEvent(input$selectcolumn, {
    rv$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -

```
library(shiny)

source('splitColumn_stack.R')

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      actionButton("Splitcolumn", "SplitColumn"),
      selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', '')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    rv$data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    
    updateSelectInput(session, 'selectcolumn', 'select column', names(rv$data))
    
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(rv$data)
    rv$data
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Splitcolumn, {
    rv$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```